# HTML Canvas: Is there a Javascript vector library that is equivalent to Processing PVector? Or a Canvas library that has a built in vector class?

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking at doing some canvas particle system. Still very new in this.

It makes sense to start thinking about vector in general. So I am looking for a vector class that could do cross product, add product, multiply... similar to PVector class in Processing.

This is the best I could find so far http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/

ProcessingJS is a direct port from Processing. But I am not looking at using ProcessingJS.

It seems that the best canvas library out there is KineticJS and EaselJS now. However both libraries don't have built in vector classes.

What are your thoughts on a good vector library? Or is there a canvas library that has built in vector class other than ProcessingJS?

Comment: EaselJS official twitter account replied me, Box2D works well with them.

Comment: There is a new active javascript library been at work right now. p5js.org It is based on processing. Read more about it and it is maintained by a bunch of very talented and trustworthy people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List of Physics library.

PhysicsJS: http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/

p2.js: https://github.com/schteppe/p2.js

verlet-js: http://subprotocol.com/verlet-js/

JPE: https://github.com/colorhook/JPE

Newton: http://hunterloftis.github.io/newton/

Matter.js: http://brm.io/matter-js/

Ammo.js: https://github.com/kripken/ammo.js/ - Automated port from bullet.js Hence the generated js code isn't optimised and it is not the easiest to use. However bullet.js is used in movies, games and softwares so you can imagine the physics is really complete and thorough.

Comment: I would love to use Box2D but it seems that there isn't a good JS port out there. The most up to date one will be Box2d.js https://github.com/kripken/box2d.js/ The creator of Ammo.js